# ftruncate() invalid arguement error

Tags: c, shared-memory

I just started learned about shared memory and we are suppose to create an object of shared memory for my assignment, but I keep getting an error when I run my program. 
   The error comes from the ftruncate() function and it keeps telling me its an invalid argument, here's my code segment for the shared memory:

```
struct container* rPtr;
int fd;

/*  Creates shared memory object and sets it size  */
fd = shm_open("/collatzRegion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if (fd == -1)
{   perror("shm_open");
    return 1;
}

if ((ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct container))) == -1)
{   perror("ftruncate");
    return 1;
}

/*  Maps shared memory object  */
rPtr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct container), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

if ( rPtr == MAP_FAILED)
{   perror("mmap");
    return 1;
}
```

and my structure, that is defined before my main(), is:

```
/* Defines "structure" of shared memory */
#define MAX_LEN 10000
struct container
{   int length;
    int buf[MAX_LEN];
};
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, it's pretty standard code structure.

Comment: hmm... I wonder why its giving me an error... Thanks though I felt like maybe I was doing it completely wrong

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you set `MAX_LEN` to something like 10?

Comment: I just tried your code with no errors.

Comment: Changing the MAX_LEN acted that same.

Comment: Barmar - What are you using to compile it ?

Comment: `mmap` may (and on many systems definitely will) complain if the size you're mapping is not a multiple of the page size. Not sure if that applies to the `ftruncate` on the shm file descriptor, but I wouldn't be surprised. Working with memory mappings that aren't a multiple of the page size can't really be well-defined. That's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!